# Timeout- and AddressAlreadyInUseException with WCF Duplex

Tags: .net, wcf, duplex

I am trying to push some information from a WCF Service to a console application, and stumbled across [this guide](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/dhananjaykumar/archive/2011/02/09/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf.aspx).

After a couple of failures trying to make it by myself I started to follow it "step by step" but everytime I get an `AddressAlreadyInUseException`, so I tried to insert a `clientBaseAddress` and then I get a `TimeoutException`.

Posted what I will think is of interest below.

Bindings and endpoints on the service

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="dualsec">
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="svcbh">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Service.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="svcbh">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="MyAddress"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint name ="duplexendpoint"
              bindingConfiguration="dualsec"
              address =""
              binding ="wsDualHttpBinding"
              contract ="Service.ICallback"
              />
    <endpoint name ="MetaDataTcpEndpoint"
              address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Bindings and endpoints for the client

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="duplexendpoint1" clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:5001" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
      transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="MyAddress/Service1.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="duplexendpoint1" contract="ServiceReference1.ICallback"
    name="duplexendpoint">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/Balder" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```